# How to trigger events in apple watchKit?

Tags: events, swift, watchkit

I wonder how to trigger events programmatically in apple watchKit. For example how to fake a touch of a button in watchKit or how to fake a long touch of the whole screen? (in swift)

Comment: Do you want to have the visual appearance of a touch on a button or do you just want to execute the action for a button?

Comment: I would like to execute an action for the InterfaceController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the selection action from a `WKInterfaceButton`.  You can however, just call the method directly on your InterfaceController.